# Can I use bash features such as word completion and scrolling in SFTP?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

Is it possible to use the bash features such as word completion, reverse search, scrolling, etc. in SFTP?

When I try the scroll feature with the up-arrow, it always writes the symbol `^^^`.

Comment: No. sftp is not a bash command prompt, so until someone modifies the sftp client to be more bash-like, it's not possible. It's like saying "I want cmd.exe prompt to be more like word so I can bold/italic" - they're two completely different environments.

Comment: SFTP is a file transfer protocol. It's not clear how you are going to use it as shell. If you are talking about Shell access, then if the remote side has name completion, then I don't see why it can't work.

Comment: I can get completion using `scp` provided I have bash-completion/zsh-completion and have configured my SSH client and `ssh-add`'ed my RSA keys and password to the SSH keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Tab completion seems to be possible in [yafc](http://yafc.sourceforge.net/).

Though I didn't try it myself. I can't imagine another way to get bash like behaviour working other than if it is implemented in the client you use. The client has to buffer the information on the other computer, or keep a connection open to access the data there on searches and everything, so I think searching for a good commandline client is your way to go.